# Removing from the output of NETSTAT

Tags: c, linux, module, linux-kernel, kernel

So I am developing a Linux Kernel Module, and want to hide an open socket on a specific port number from the output of `sudo netstat -nap`

What is the approach that I should take?

Comment: Your question is poorly phrased. Please take a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Jesse Give me a hand here. For the future, I will follow that. For now, if you can, give me a hand.

Comment: Run 'strace netstat -nap' to see the system calls that are made.  Looks like it is getting much of this info from /proc/net/tcp and the other tables.  The kernel net stack is putting this info there, so you would likely have to filter there.  Obviously, this is not a recommended practice.  I have not looked into which file(s) you would need to touch, but likely under linux/net/ in the kernel source (start with the proc handler).

Comment: @user2360373 I would help, but unfortunately, I haven't touched linux kernel modules outside of an university class.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? System administrators would hate you!

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to find out how "netstat" acquire socket state from system. It is said that it read from /proc/net/tcp.
Then, find out the kernel module which write socket state into "/proc/net/tcp" and modify that.